# Internal Server error while opening axis2 server

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat

I have downloaded the axis2.war(1.7.4) file from the apache website.

I put it in the tomcat/webapps folder and it automatically creates a axis2 folder.

I open my web browser and navigate to http://localhost:7070/axis2/ and get the page that has services, validate and administration.

The problem is that if I click on any of the Administration links a page with the apache logo is shown saying internal server error.

I am using Java(jdk1.8.0_45) and apache-tomcat-8.5.12

Can anyone explain what is causing this error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you get an error message in the console or a log file?

Comment: On Browser Console, after providing proper authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try axis 1.6.4. Same error and that version works for me.